# Change the window size for "py.exe"

Tags: python

I am reading and writing files to the 'py.exe' screen. I have a *.py script that I double click which pops up the 'py.exe' window, where I operate within.

Its all fine, but the default window dimensions are a bit landscape-y and I want to save having to "windows+leftcursor" all the time.

**I want to change the default dimensions of the py.exe window to what I want them to be.**

```
import easygui

filenames=easygui.fileopenbox('Welcome',default='c:\data\*.ers',multiple=True)

for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename) as f:
               print("\n\n" + filename + "\n\n", f)
```

[py.exe window that I want to change its default dimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDkdm.png)

Comment: I do not understand the problem. Could you give us more information?

Comment: Show screenshot of your window

Comment: On Windows you would be better using the properties entry on the console window's system menu to modify the shortcut used to launch `py.exe` (possibly creating a copy of the shortcut initially).

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
os.system("mode con cols=100 lines=300")
```

ever better now I use win32gui to locate the window in a certain position and size

```
import win32gui
hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32gui.MoveWindow(hwnd, 100, 0, 1100, 1000, True)
```

you need to install pywin32 first

```
pip install pywin32
```